# iOS firebase database design problem : Best way to design chat app for cloud firestore?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Im working with Chat App. My firebase cloud store look like this

Messages = holding a whole messages from every users , every single messages from the beginning of service's release gathered here . It might contain 1,000,000,000,000 ~ messages

```
Messages | msg1                    | msgID = msg1
         | msg2                    | roomID = room03
         | msg3                    | content = "HELLO"
         | ....... msg100,000,000  |

Rooms    | room01  |  roomID : room01
         | room02  |  memberIDs : user1 , user2 , user3
         | room03  |  messageIDs : msg1001 , msg2088 , msg991090
```

What i know : i can fetch 1 message from those billions of messages easily with

```
db.collection("Messages").whereField("roomID", isEqualTo: "msg1001")
    .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
```

What i Dont know , and i need to know 
: How can i fetch all "messages" related to "one room"

***What i Want : An array of 1,000 messages , ordered by timestamp***

for example , room100 contain an array of messageIDs , up to 1,000 messagesIDs

```
| room100  |  messageIDs : msg1001 , msg2088 , msg991090 ..... msg9999999
```

Should i fetch it like this ?

```
for a in messageIDs {
      db.collection("Messages").whereField("roomID", isEqualTo: "msg1001")
     .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in ......
   }
 }
```

I suppose not , this would created multiple , 1,000 parallel threads.
I cant predict which node would finished first , I would got the final result as unordered array of messages

Or Should i fetch it like this ?
Nested requests , for fully ordered messages

```
db.collection("Messages").whereField("roomID", isEqualTo: "msg1001")
         .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in 

           db.collection("Messages").whereField("roomID", isEqualTo: "msg1002")
     .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in 

       db.collection("Messages").whereField("roomID", isEqualTo: "msg1003")
     .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in 

       *....... and so on , 1000 nested requests*
     }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Whats the right way to fetch  , validate and compare multiple groupID ????????????????

Comment: Multiple queries don't create multiple threads.  All queries are pipelined over a single connection in a single thread.

Comment: If you are interested, I have explained in one of my **[tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb)** how you can create a Chat App using Cloud Firestore. You'll also find the way in which you can structure your database [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u3KwKQddPoo&index=3&list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb&t=182s).